# Decrement NaturalNumber using recursion question

Tags: java

I do not understand why the recursion problem of this code I wrote works, below I will show what the function that is used in the code below from the library used in my university

**void multiplyBy10(int k)**

**Multiplies this by 10 and adds k.**

**Parameters:**

**k - the int to be added**

**Updates:**

**this**

**Requires:**

**0 <= k < 10**

**Ensures:**

**this = 10 * #this + k**

and divideBy10 simply divides the natural number by 10 and returns the remainder and NaturalNumber.RADIX is simply a constant equal to 10.

```
private static void decrement(NaturalNumber n) {
    assert n != null : "Violation of: n is not null";
    assert !n.isZero() : "Violation of: n > 0";

    int digit = n.divideBy10();
    digit = digit - 1;
    if (digit == NaturalNumber.RADIX) {
        digit = 0;
        decrement(n);
    } else if (digit < 0) {
        digit = 9;
        decrement(n);
    }
    n.multiplyBy10(digit);

}
```

Now the code does work, if you input any number it will decrease it by 1, although I am a bit confused as to why

Comment: What about the code confuses you?

Comment: Are you confused about how recursion reach the end of calculation?

Comment: I am confused as to how the program itself decrements, especially why if digit is less than 0 but setting it to 9 and just using recursion reduces it by 1 from say 10 to 9.

Answer (score 1):

First of all. Thats exactly the reason why classes like NaturalNumber should be immutable. Using a static method for applying changes on an instance is a violation of the open-closed-principle.

'int digit = n.divideBy10();' changes the value of n. Otherwise this method would not terminate.

I assume that you call 'n.multiplyBy10(-1)'. This would explain the correct result for numbers<10.

Which input arguments have you tested for this method?

Comment: n.multiplyBy10(k) where k has to be between 0 (inclusive) and 10 (exclusive), it decrements any natural numbers, I tested between 1-10 and 5000, 500000, 499 and all of them decremented by 1.

Comment: what confuses me is what happens to digit in the case where digit is less than 0, what happens to digit = 9, and then decrement, lets take n = 10 as an example, n = 10 going in then becomes 1, digit equals to remainder which is 0 then it becomes -1, then digit resets to 9, and decrement is done again with n = 1, and digit as it is the remainder is equal to 1 then it becomes 0, but since it was already 9 before being entered recursively does that take precedence over the 0 it should become when digit reset itself during recursion?

Comment: The value of digit will not been overwritten during recursion. Every method call has its own digit variable.